# show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_nq^n$ is convergent using Cauchy condition for uniform convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_nq^n$$is convergent using Cauchy condition for uniform convergence of series?  $|q|<1,|\alpha_n|<M$  $\forall n\in\Bbb{N}$

$$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\overline n,\forall n>\overline n,\forall k\in \Bbb{N} \left |\sum_{i=n}^{n+k}a_i\right|<\epsilon$$

I think it should have been done by taking $\varepsilon>0$ and then $\overline n>(\text{something dependent from }\varepsilon  ) $

But the one idea I had was to take geometric series and it is convergence but this won't be from that definition I guess.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\Bigl|\sum_{i=n}^{n+k}\alpha_i\,q^i\Bigr|\le M\sum_{i=n}^{n+k}|q|^i\le M\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}|q|^i=M\frac{|q|^n}{1-|q|}.
$$